# Azure CLI & escape quote

Tags: azure-cli

I'm failing to escape QUOTE " character on AZ CLI command.

I need to remotly execute the command : C:\"Program Files"\Outlook\outlook.exe
So, I use RunPowerShellScript command of AZ CLI with start-process.

call az vm run-command invoke --command-id RunPowerShellScript --name xxx -g yyy --scripts "Start-Process C:\"Program Files"\Outlook\outlook.exe" --output yaml

I tryed many option like :

C:\"Program Files"\

C:\""Program Files""\

C:\"Program Files\"\

C:\^"Program Files^"\

C:`"Program Files`"\

Nothing works, always an error.

Any idea please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact, you do not need to escape quotes, you can directly use FilePath. So you could use `"Start-Process 'C:\Program Files\Outlook\outlook.exe'"`. For example, I have a `Putty.exe` in the path `C:\Program Files\PuTTY` of my remote VM.

[image]

The problem is that command `az vm run-command invoke` execute scripts remotely on the VM. The contents included `--scripts` parameter are running on the remote VM. Make sure the scripts include a valid path in remote VM instead of local VM. If the file in the scripts does not exist on remote VM. You probably face this message.

[image]

Read more details: [Run PowerShell scripts in your Windows VM with Run Command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/run-command).

Comment: hi Nancy, thanks for the help
This guide me a lot and i was able to launch my script :)
call az vm run-command invoke --command-id RunPowerShellScript --name xxx -g yyy --scripts "Start-Process 'C:\Program Files\Outlook\outlook.exe'" --output yaml